# Detect rectangle shape OpenCv

Tags: opencv, object, shapes, cascade, haar-classifier

I need to detect a rectangle shape (card) in real time, using some javascript library like (js Feat or Tracking Js).

I trained a Haar classifier, but I'm not getting the precision i need. So, I am thinking about using a rectangle detector instead of a cascade xml.

Somebody could give me a hand with this?

Thanks very much and sorry for my english (I am from Argentina).

Comment: looking into this as well for validating credential capture quality over webrtc